# Trying to match components in a pair

Tags: haskell

```
lookUp :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
lookUp x xs = [if x `elem` xs then tail(xs) else head(xs) | x <- xs]
```

There is a type error but I'm not sure why. I'm trying to find the first component of the pair and return the second component, or return x if the input isn't part of a pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is a `Char`, while `xs` is meant to be a list of `(Char, Char)` tuples. The `elem` function has the following type, so yes, you will get a type error.

```
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

This function makes more sense returning `Maybe Char`, as the key you're searching for may not exist in the list. We know the key won't exist in an empty list. Otherwise we can recursively iterate over the list testing each tuple as we go.

```
lookup :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Maybe Char
lookup _ [] = Nothing
lookup ch ((x, ch'):xs) 
  | ch == x =   -- fill in the blanks
  | otherwise = -- fill in the blanks
```